# I have a python TypeError and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: python

So I have the following code:

```
import random

pizza_toppings = ["bacon", "cheese", "chicken", "pepperoni", "olives"]
pizza_sauce = ["alfredo", "marinara", "ranch", "BBQ"]

def pizza(number_of_toppings):
  final_sauce = random.choice(pizza_sauce)
  final_toppings = []
  for i in range(number_of_toppings):
    final_topping = random.choice(pizza_toppings)
    final_topping(final_toppings)
  final_result = print("Your pizza with ", final_topping, " with ", final_sauce, " is ready I guess...")
  return final_result
pizza(2)
```

It's giving me the error "TypeError: 'str' object not callable." How do I fix this?

Comment: Side comment - `print()` does not return the printed string; it returns `None`.  So this function always returns `None`.

Comment: `final_toppings = random.sample(pizza_toppings, k=number_of_toppings)`. No loop needed.

Comment: Please provide the **entire** error message. Have you done any debugging, or any research?

Answer (score 6):

I assume this line

```
final_topping(final_toppings)
```

should be

```
final_toppings.append(final_topping)
```

Also the return of `print` is `None`, so `final_result` will be `None`.

Comment: I had tried that, but it's giving me a new error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Read carefully, `final_toppings` is a `list`, `final_topping` is a `str`, make sure you're using the correct objects

Answer (score 1):

I replaced `final_toppings` by `final_toppings_list` so it makes it clearer :

```
import random

pizza_toppings = ["bacon", "cheese", "chicken", "pepperoni", "olives"]
pizza_sauce = ["alfredo", "marinara", "ranch", "BBQ"]

def pizza(number_of_toppings):
  final_sauce = random.choice(pizza_sauce)
  final_toppings_list = []
  for i in range(number_of_toppings):
    final_topping = random.choice(pizza_toppings)
    final_toppings_list.append(final_topping)
  final_result = "Your pizza with ", final_toppings_list, " with ", final_sauce, " is ready I guess..."
  return final_result
print(pizza(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

It´s because you´re using the string `final_topping` as a function. Just delete that line and you´re good.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to append `final_topping` to a `final_toppings` list if you want to use only one element of your `pizza_toppings` list (later in `final_result`).

I commented the two lines in your script and used python [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) to format `final_result` in a convenient way..

```python
import random


pizza_toppings = ["bacon", "cheese", "chicken", "pepperoni", "olives"]
pizza_sauce = ["alfredo", "marinara", "ranch", "BBQ"]


def pizza(number_of_toppings):
    final_sauce = random.choice(pizza_sauce)
    #final_toppings = []

    for i in range(number_of_toppings):
        final_topping = random.choice(pizza_toppings)
        #final_toppings.append(final_topping)

    final_result = (
        f"Your pizza with {final_topping} "
        f"and {final_sauce} is ready I guess..."
    )

    return final_result


print(pizza(2))
```